# What is wrong with my nested loops in Python?

Tags: python, loops, nested

How do I make nested loops in Python (version 3.0)?

I am trying to get the following loops to show me the products of two numbers:

```
def PrintProductsBelowNumber(number):
    number1 = 1
    number2 = 1
    while number1 <= number:
        while number2 <= number:
            print(number1, "*", number2, "=", number1 * number2)
            number2 += 1
        number1 += 1

PrintProductsBelowNumber(2)
```

As a result I get:

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
```

So it seems the outer loop over number1 does not run.

How do I get the loop over number1 to run, and thus obtain:

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you aren't setting number2 back to 1 after the inner loop completes the first time. number1 then increments, but since number2 is still too high the inner loop doesn't run again.

```
def PrintProductsBelowNumber(number):
    number1 = 1
    while number1 <= number:
        number2 = 1
        while number2 <= number:
            print(number1, "*", number2, "=", number1 * number2)
            number2 += 1
        number1 += 1

PrintProductsBelowNumber(2)
```

**EDIT**: Adam's solution is much better in general, but this is to show why your's wasn't working the way you thought it should in the first place.

Comment: @Mike Boers: Thanks for your answer. Yes, your example clearly shows me why my piece of code didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 14):

`number2` only gets initialized once, you need to re-initialize it for each iteration of the inner loop.  However, this code is very C-like and not very Pythonic.  The better way to do it would be to use the `for number in range(n)` construct:

```
def PrintProductsBelowNumber(number):
    for number1 in range(1, number+1):
        for number2 in range(1, number+1):
            print(number1, "*", number2, "=", number1 * number2)
```

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Thanks for the answer; and thanks for showing me the Pythonic way...

Answer (score 0):

You could modify Adam's solution with a list comprehension:

```
def PrintProductsBelowNumber(number):

    results = [(i, j, i * j) for i in range(1, number + 1) 
                             for j in range(1, number + 1)]

    for number1, number2, result in results:
        print(number1, "*", number2, "=", result)
```

or some variation thereof.